# Windows batch file check multiple files in a directory with date extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to command scripting.

I need to check if multiple files are available in a directory.

I am able to check the files with the exact names using below script but need direction when the files are with date in the name as shown. the date is as of yesterday, yyyymmdd.

example:  metric_cal_enc.20120415.txt, reg_nyc_enc.20120415.txt, ferm_det_enc.20120415.txt

```
@echo off
echo Check if files are existent in inbound directory
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  echo Checking path %%a
  if EXIST %%a (
    echo Exists!
  ) else (
    echo Does Not Exist %%a >> log.txt
  )
)
```

Comment: Are you saying the date is the actual extension of the file? Like abc_file.20140325? Or just that the date is in the filename like your example shows? Are you using the current day as your criteria?

Comment: the date is in the filename and it is the previous day.

Comment: Do they always match the format `*_*_yyyymmdd`?

Comment: the file name can be different,abc_file_yyyymmdd.txt, bca_file_yyyymmdd.txt, cba_file_yyyymmdd.txt

Comment: You're not making this easy ;) I still need to know what you're using for your criteria for the date. Edit your post and put up around 10 of your actual file names, that will clear up a lot.

Comment: the date will always remain same for all the files on a given day. the date on the file is always the previous days. i updated the post. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, for lack of an example, that your `test.txt` file contains

```
metric_cal_enc.txt
reg_nyc_enc.txt
ferm_det_enc.txt
```

and you have `%yesterday%` set up to yesterday's date (**don't** use a variable `%date%`)

```
if EXIST %%~na.%yesterday%%%~xa (
```

is the only change you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

And here is how you can get Yesterdays date:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Echo %Year% %Month% %Day%
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -1 Ret
echo %Ret%
exit /b


:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%YYYY: =%%MM: =%%DD: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
exit /b

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
     IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
     IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
     IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```